# Object Stream vs Text Stream - Who's Faster? Java

Tags: java

I am doing a work that i need to measure the time to write and read with Object Streams and with Text Streams. I was expecting that the Object Streams was faster than Text Streams but , my results was exactly the opposite situation for both situations(read and write).
Can someone tell me which is normally faster?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you're sending and how you encode it into text.

Comment: "Who cares"? :-) One of the biggest "performance boosters" in my experience is using a Buffered layer. In any case, consider *how* an Object Stream differs from just plain text, and what it implies.

Comment: Serializing to something like protobuf might be faster than both.  Compressing on write and decompressing on read might speed things up.

Answer (score 4):

Why did you think that Object streams would be faster? They have high overhead. Many people prefer other serialization mechanisms.

Comment: I thought that the Object Streams was faster in my case due that for example when i'm reading from a text, i'm reading line by line and everytime i need to use split in order to gather the information of the object, i thought then is going be more slow due to constantly split. Didn't know that Object Streams have a high overhead,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Object streams carry quite a bit of overhead since they need to serialize and deserialize class information. They can be reasonably efficient for large object graphs and arrays where the number of unique classes is small, but are notoriously bad for small messages. Object serialisation also has to do quite a bit of bookkeeping (e.g. to detect cycles in object graphs and ensure each object sent only once when there are multiple references to it)

Text streams on the other hand are very simple and carry little overhead. It's not surprising that they are faster in your tests.

Though it does depend a lot on how you encode your data into text: some naive text representations of object graphs would actually be much worse than regular Java object serialisation. Basically, it would be a bad idea to try and reinvent Java object serialisation in text form.....

If you are interested in fast and efficient serialisation of objects, you should also consider:

- Advanced objects serialization libraries like Goggle's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/)
- Efficient textual data representation formats like JSON or Clojure s-expressions (both of which have good library support and are proven in the field)